# Predefined Oracle db function that converts fraction to decimal

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there any Oracle db predefined function that converts a decimal to a fraction and vice versa?

Take for example:

If I pass it 0.9 value, then it should give 90/100. Or I send 90/100 to the function, I would get back 0.9.

Comment: Why 90/100 and not 9/10? Do you always want the result as X/100? Besides that, I believe there's no built-in, but you can define you own function if you need.

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this..

```
 select (0.9 *  100  || '/100') as YourColumn from dual;

 Select (yourcolumn * 100 || '/100') as col1 from yourtable;
```

Comment: The `to_char` is redundant at the moment, because of where you have the closing parenthesis. The `0.9 * 100` is being implicitly converted to a string before it's concatenated with the `'/100'`. So the input to `to_char` is already a string.